# How to detect mouse scroll and mouse position in Python and then make some actions with it?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I would like to make a program for displaying some information and help (like it is sometimes done at libraries or in other public places). So basically some information screen. The problem is I would like to prevent the user from exiting the program and scrolling up, to see what others typed.
I would like to do that without importing big libraries like Pygame. There are plenty of modules for automatic mouse movement and and mouse clicks, but almost no modules for detecting it. If you know some please write them here. I am using Windows 10 and 7.

Comment: I know.  I asked for your opinions and experiences.

Answer (score 1):

Try pynput. It's a bit fiddly to use when capturing, but can capture keyboard and mouse and also emit both.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't really answer the question asked in the title:

However it might answer the use case that you describe:

I don't have a windows computer at hand for testing:

but perhaps this could work:

```
import os
os.system('cls')
# now rewrite the lines, that a user is allowed to see.
```

Theoretically cls is supposed to clean the windows screen buffer and you wouldn't see any history and it should be impossible to scroll back.

I think most other solutions would quickly become complicated or could be circumvented by a user with some combinations of key presses and mouse movements.

However you had to explicitely rewrite whatever you want to keep on the display.

Comment: Is it possible to specify, which lines need to be erased?

Comment: no with cls you delete everything. and you what just redaw the lines that you'd like to keep.

Normally this should be fast enough you might see a small flicker, but that's all